# How to target individual children's hover css classes using Tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

How can I make it so that the direct children of a parent div have a css class applied to each one of them individually? For example, if I want each item to be `font-bold` on hover state. I'm hoping to do this inline using the `class=` attribute vs. having it defined in a css file.

Html:

```
<div class="[&>a]:hover:font-bold">
  <a>link 1</a>
  <a>link 2</a>
</div>
```

If I hover any one of those `<a>` children, then *all* of the `<a>` become bold. I want each one of them to become bold when they're hovered over without affecting their siblings.

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pjrw8j?file=index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#ordering-stacked-modifiers), sometimes variant order matters:

> ### Ordering stacked modifiers
>
> When stacking modifiers, they are applied from the inside-out, like nested function calls:
>
> ```js
> // These modifiers:
> 'dark:group-hover:focus:opacity-100'
>
> // ...are applied like this:
> dark(groupHover(focus('opacity-100')))
> ```
>
> For the most part this doesn’t actually matter, but there are a few situations where the order you use actually generates meaningfully different CSS.

In your situation, you have `[&>a]:hover:` which is conceptually like `[&>a](hover(…))`. This would evaluate to:

1. `hover:` – hover this `<div>` element.
2. `[&>a]:` - select direct `<a>` child elements within this `<div>` element.

Whereas really, it seems like you'd want the reverse, `hover:[&>a]:`:

1. `[&>a]:` - select direct `<a>` child elements within this `<div>` element.
2. `hover:` – hover this element (the direct `<a>` child elements within this `<div>` element).

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="hover:[&>a]:font-bold">
  <a>link 1</a>
  <a>link 2</a>
</div>
```